# Google Analytics Real time bind

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

I have setup my application in google analytics.

***App information :***

Angular 1.4.10,
Google analytics setup.

**Question :**

When I was tracking the page views I see even URL related to the api calls are recorded.

Anyone know why is it recording API/Calls and due to which all the API calls are making to the top visited . We are not able to track proper page visits.

**Example:**

website is ww.abcd.com 
 api call are /api/getsearch 
 redirect page : www.abcd.com/search?keyword=something

real time page views are recorded as both:

- */api/getsearch*
- */search?keyword=something*

Do any one know why these calls are recorded and why are these recorded in the page views and how to not record them.